# Rust: как получить разницу между двумя датами и временем в Chrono?

Tags: rust

Нужно сравнить два значения (текущее время и прошедшее) и взять только то, что старше 5 минут.
Не получается сравнить - не могу понять как это сделать в chrono. Возможно мой косяк в том, что у них разные форматы ?

```
use chrono::prelude::*;

pub trait AnyExt {
    fn type_name(&self) -> &'static str;
}

impl<T> AnyExt for T {
    fn type_name(&self) -> &'static str {
        std::any::type_name::<T>()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let now = Local::now().format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3f");
    let dt = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("2023-10-14 17:54:03,221", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3f").unwrap();
    
    //chrono::format::formatting::DelayedFormat<chrono::format::strftime::StrftimeItems>
    println!("{}", now.type_name()); 

    
    //chrono::naive::datetime::NaiveDateTime
    println!("{}", dt.type_name());
    
    //let diff = now.signed_duration_since(dt);
}
```

Ссылка на [пример](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a2350decd5901cacb55b23d33505c60)

Answer (score 1):

Вроде разобрался. Может конечно есть более правильный вариант.

```
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let now = Local::now().naive_local();
    let _dt = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str("2023-10-14 17:54:03,221", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3f").unwrap();
    
    let diff = now.signed_duration_since(_dt);
    let dur = diff.num_seconds();
    
    println!("{:?}", dur);
}
```